# function getelementbyid not outputting to correct place

Tags: javascript, function, layout, onclick, getelementbyid

I am making a form to add players into an event.
The form searches a db of players with search criteria specified by the user and then lists all matching players with an add button next to them.
I also have a table with all the table headers done and then a

```
<div id="PlayerAdded">
```

tag before the end of the table.

I have written a function to output the data for the next row to the table when a players "Add" button is clicked. My function says:

```
function add(){
    document.getElementById("PlayerAdded").innerHTML += "<tr><td>success</td></tr>";
}
```

I expected this to add a row, but instead it adds just the word "success" above the table (Perhaps I was a little optimistic when I used the word success as my test string lol).
Can someone please tell me why it is not adding the code inside the div "PlayerAdded"?

If it helps, here is some of the HTML:

```
<table border='1px'>
<tr><th colspan='6'> <?php echo ($eName . " - " . $vn); ?></th></tr>
<tr><th>Player ID</th>
<th>Player Name</th>
<th>Place</th>
<th>Points</th>
<th>Cash</th>
<th>Ticket?</th></tr>

<div id="PlayerAdded"> </div>

<tr><td colspan='3'>Search <input type='text' id='newsearch'></input>
</table>
```

Comment: You can't have a `<div>` directly inside `<table>`.

Comment: Put an id on the last `<tr>`, and use `insertBefore()` to insert a row before it.

Comment: Thank you! I don't have a teacher, so a lot of my learning has been through forums and online tools, but I never learnt this! Thank heaps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a couple of problems with your existing HTML - which therefore broke your DOM when the browser attempted to assemble things.

1. a `<div>` element – in a `<table>` – *must* be contained within either a `<th>` or `<td>` element; no other element is a valid child of a `<tr>` element, and the only valid children of a `<table>` element are `<thead>`, `<tfoot>`, `<tbody>` and `<tr>` elements.
2. neither your last `<tr>`, or its child `<td>`, element were closed – the browser will automatically close these elements when it encounters another `<td>` (since neither a `<td>`, nor a `<tr>`, can be directly nested within another `<td>`).

That said, I'd correct your HTML to the following:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th colspan='6'>&laquo; php response &raquo;</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Player ID</th>
            <th>Player Name</th>
            <th>Place</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Cash</th>
            <th>Ticket?</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='3'>Search
                <input type='text' id='newsearch' />
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="addNewRow">Add a new row</button>
```

And your JavaScript to the following:

```
function addNewRow() {

  // creating the relevant elements to be added:
  var row = document.createElement('tr'),
    td = document.createElement('td');

  // setting the text of the created-<td> element:
  td.textContent = 'Success';

  // setting the colSpan property (the colspan attribute):
  td.colSpan = '6';

  // adding a class-name to the created-<td>, to make it
  // visually obvious which are the newly-added <td>
  // elements:
  td.classList.add('addedRow');

  // appending the created-<td> to the created-<tr>:
  row.appendChild(td);

  // finding the last <tr> of the table, using
  // document.querySelector() which will match
  // only the first element that matches the
  // supplied CSS selector (or null, if no
  // element exists that matches):
  var lastRow = document.querySelector('table tr:last-child');

  // inserting the created-<tr> (and its descendant
  // elements parentNode of the lastRow node before
  // the lastRow node):
  lastRow.parentNode.insertBefore(row, lastRow);
}

// using unobtrusive JavaScript to add the 'click'
// event-listener to the <button> element with the
// id of 'addNewRow':
document.getElementById('addNewRow').addEventListener('click', addNewRow);
```

```js
function addNewRow() {
    var row = document.createElement('tr'),
        td = document.createElement('td');
    
    td.textContent = 'Success';
    td.colSpan = '6';
    td.classList.add('addedRow');
    
    row.appendChild(td);
    
    var lastRow = document.querySelector('table tr:last-child');
    
    lastRow.parentNode.insertBefore(row, lastRow);
}

document.getElementById('addNewRow').addEventListener('click', addNewRow);
```

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-height: 2em;
}
td.addedRow {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan='6'>&laquo; php response &raquo;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Player ID</th>
      <th>Player Name</th>
      <th>Place</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Cash</th>
      <th>Ticket?</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='3'>Search
        <input type='text' id='newsearch' />
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="addNewRow">Add a new row</button>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ed56mphn/3/), for experimentation or development.

References:

- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).
- [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).

Answer (score 1):

Try doing as user @Barmar said:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function add(){
    var _tr = document.createElement("tr");
    var _textNode = document.createTextNode("Success");
    _tr.appendChild(_textNode);
    var _child = document.getElementById("botTr");
    var parentDiv = _child.parentNode;

    parentDiv.insertBefore(_tr, botTr);
}
</script>
```

And then:

```
<table border='1px'>
<tr><th colspan='6'> <?php echo ($eName . " - " . $vn); ?> </th></tr>
<tr id="topTr"><th>Player ID</th>
<th>Player Name</th>
<th>Place</th>
<th>Points</th>
<th>Cash</th>
<th>Ticket?</th>
</tr>

<tr id="botTr"><td colspan='3'>Search <input type='text' id='newsearch' />
</table>
<input type="button" name="hitme" id="hitme" value="hitme" onclick="add();" />
```

Comment: It's also invalid to have text directly within a `<tr>` element; it must be contained within either a `<td>` or `<th>` element.

Comment: Are you sure? Since I'm in the same `<td>` wouldn't I be able to create a text node for the `<tr>` as it is? I mean, this code worked, but I don't want to propagate something wrong.